# Google Sign In inside a captive portal doesn't work and Google doesn't reply the messages

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin, captiveportal

I sell a Captive portal solution that needs to use the Google Login API and for some devices (IOS and Xiaomi, for example), google returns "disallowed useragent". Following Google's @nvnagr response on another thread, I sent a message to oauth-feedback@google.com but they don't ever reply. Does anyone know another way to communicate with google about this?

Comment: The problem is that Google does not provide free support except for billing questions (the same with all the cloud vendors). You will probably need paid support.

Comment: I guess I will look for a paid suport page somwhere.

Comment: https://console.cloud.google.com/support/cases/options

Comment: thanks John for the link. I will look into it.